# Can't install ctorrent with brew

Tags: high-sierra, install, homebrew, torrent

Please help me with this issue. I followed the instruction [here](http://academictorrents.com/about.php#downloading) to download ctorrent with:
`brew install ctorrent`

but it turned out errors like this:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "ctorrent"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps
```

I sought for the workaround but haven't found out yet. Below is my system information:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.6
BuildVersion:   17G10021
Homebrew 2.2.13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The said formula is no longer available to install via Homebrew. You'd need to download and install it from the project homepage here:

[Enhanced CTorrent](http://www.rahul.net/dholmes/ctorrent/)